# How to use code coverage in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I know about new feature in Xcode 7 - **Code Coverage**. I know how to turn it on:

go to **Edit scheme** -> **Test** -> **Info** tab -> enable **Gather coverage data**.

I did it, run tests, and... Where is **Test Report** for my tests?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since you turned it on in your scheme, and then build and test:

[image]

[image]

Go to your **Report navigator**

[image]

Then select your last test:
[image]

Finally choose Coverage tab:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remember also to enabled test coverage in your bot settings, there is new picker in Xcode 7 (Disabled by default)

[image]

Comment: What is "bot settings"?

Comment: When you use a OSX Server and enable Xcode server, you must create a bot to perform actions (builds, tests, distribution, etc.). Know more reading "continuous integration":
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/