# How to get test coverage for only one test in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode7, code-coverage

I use XCode 7.2 and Swift 2.0, no extra pods for testing, just XCTestCase class. I don't have `@testable import myApp` and adding it doesn't fix my problem.

I have everything set up correctly to see code coverage for my Swift project (I have set it up following this post - [How to use code coverage in Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096924/how-to-use-code-coverage-in-xcode-7) ).

And it works, **when I run all tests** (with Command-U). However, when I try to run a **particular test class** (e.g. CuriousUITests: XCTestCase) or a **specific test** (e.g. testMyFavouriteButton), the coverage shows as if none of the code is covered!

Why does that happen?

I want to be able to see code coverage when running just one test, so that after implementing a new test, I don't have to run all of my tests to see if it indeed does cover what I expected (It just takes too long to run them all).

Thanks for all your help!

da-na