# Xcode 9 code coverage on unit tests showing wrong %

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

The Code Coverage report generated by XCode 9 seems to be off on some files in my project.
It shows 0% in one of the class file
[image]
While when I check  the codes it actually covered by the test
[image]

It looks like that the coverage report is actually in-sync with the tests???

Environment:
Xcode 9.2
Swift 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll find the answer here [Code coverage result is not accurate to real coverage in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976820/code-coverage-result-is-not-accurate-to-real-coverage-in-xcode-7)

Briefly it says to use

```
@testable import <yourapp>
```

In each test file and don't add your app .swift files to the test targets.

Works for me.